# Get-ACL returns nothing / null

Tags: powershell

```
New-Item $tempPathFull -ItemType Directory
$tempACL = Get-ACL -Path $tempPathFull
```

$tempACL is null / nothing. The directory exists after creating it on the share and I have full control rights. What could be potential reasons for getting "null"? The microsoft documentation says nothing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got a square bracket in your directory name?  Square brackets are wildcard characters that the `-Path` parameter tries to resolve.

Try:

```
$tempACL = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $tempPathFull
```

See `Get-Help about_Wildcards` for more information.

Technically, you could also use this if you had to use the `-Path` variable for some reason:

```
$tempACL = Get-Acl -Path ([Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($tempPathFull))
```